# Apache HTTPAsyncClient closes connection before response

Tags: https, maven-surefire-plugin, apache-httpasyncclient

I am sending a GET request to an API using the Apache AsyncHTTPClient version 4.1.4 (latest). I can't seem to get a response from the server.

This is my request log.

```
Jun 04, 2020 3:40:01 PM org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec generateRequest
FINE: [exchange: 2] Connection route established
Jun 04, 2020 3:40:01 PM org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec generateRequest
FINE: [exchange: 2] Attempt 1 to execute request
Jun 04, 2020 3:40:01 PM org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec generateRequest
FINE: [exchange: 2] Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Jun 04, 2020 3:40:01 PM org.apache.http.headers onRequestSubmitted
FINE: http-outgoing-1 >> GET /v1/contact?id=24 HTTP/1.1
Jun 04, 2020 3:40:01 PM org.apache.http.headers onRequestSubmitted
FINE: http-outgoing-1 >> Authorization: Bearer <token_removed>
Jun 04, 2020 3:40:01 PM org.apache.http.headers onRequestSubmitted
FINE: http-outgoing-1 >> Host: api.trial.ezyvet.com
Jun 04, 2020 3:40:01 PM org.apache.http.headers onRequestSubmitted
FINE: http-outgoing-1 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
Jun 04, 2020 3:40:01 PM org.apache.http.headers onRequestSubmitted
FINE: http-outgoing-1 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpAsyncClient/4.1.4 (Java/11.0.6)
Jun 04, 2020 3:40:01 PM org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.ManagedNHttpClientConnectionImpl setEvent
FINE: http-outgoing-1 192.168.1.2:52932<->52.27.52.37:443[ACTIVE][rw:][ACTIVE][rw][NEED_UNWRAP][0][0][437]: Event set [w]
Jun 04, 2020 3:40:01 PM org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec requestCompleted
FINE: [exchange: 2] Request completed
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 14.622 s
```

When I send the same request using Postman, I get a successful response.

This is my code to handle the connection.

```java
public void connect(HttpUriRequest request, FutureCallback<HttpResponse> callback) {
    SSLContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = new SSLContextBuilder();

    try {
        sslContextBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());

        try (CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
                .setSSLContext(sslContextBuilder.build())
                .setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
                .build()) {
            client.start();
            client.execute(request, callback).get();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.getGlobal().severe("Couldn't execute the request using the AsyncClient.");
    }
}
```

My debugger won't get triggered in any of the callback's methods (completed, failed, cancelled). Apparently the connection gets terminated for some reason.

Can someone explain what is happening here?
Thanks

Comment: I suspect that you might be shutting down the client before the server response is fully transmitted. Post your application code.

Comment: Please check this gist: https://gist.github.com/samindaperamuna/edadce4029e9060755c1e1928553a177

Comment: I am using IntelliJ Community Edition and I think this is an issue withe the IDEs JUnit execution. When I added a `Thread.sleep(5000);` after the connection starts, it runs fine.

Comment: This has to do nothing with the IDE. HttpAsyncClient API is event driven and you are likely using it incorrectly without proper event synchronization. Thread#sleep might solve the immediate problem but it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this issue by changing the code to include a `CountDownLatch` instead of using `client.execute(request, callback).get()`.

I passed down the latch to where the `HttpResponse` is read by JSON deserializer and count it down after everything completes.

This answer helped a lot.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49359725/6663366